# Is it a zombie?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system-calls, zombie-process

I have some doubt regarding the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) sleep(5);
    printf("Hello World %d %d\n",getpid(),pid);
    if(pid>0) while(1){sleep(1);}
    if(pid==0) printf("In child process!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Will the child process ever terminate? Will it remain in zombie state?

Comment: A process left hanging around as zombie had ended, its pid is just not removed from the list of processes to give the parent a chance of taking notice of the child's termination. To do so that parent shall call `wait()` or `waitpid()` or ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the child process dies but the parent doesn't know about it's `exit` status.  As such, the child (now *zombie*) is left in the process table.

Moreover, the parent continues to *wait* for the child and keeps running.

Comment: is it the case that unless and until parent executes wait() the child reamins a zombie(given that the child finished first)?

Comment: what could be the possible use of not 'releasing' the child?

Comment: @user2545792: To avoid races.

Comment: @alk could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user2545792: All the parent knows about its child is the child's pid. If the child would go away immediately after having ended, its pid could be taken over by another process, the latter might happend without having been realised by the parent, which in turn could lead to the "misunderstanding" the parent assuming the **new** process now carring the pid of the parent's (already ended) child **is** its child. If the parent relies on the existance of the child this would be fatal.

Comment: @alk, thanks for that explanation. I always wondered about the zombie state and why the parent should need to wait for it.

Comment: The main "use case" for not releasing the child is commonly known as a "bug".  (That is, there really is no reason to not `wait` on the child, and failure to do so is almost always a coding error.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is zombie ... your Child process dies and your parent does not know the exit status of child process. and parent process is running even after child dies.

ZOMBIE process: when child  process dies parent process still running. in this case parent process does not know the exit status of child.
To avoid this parent process uses `wait` or  `waitpid` to know the `child status`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to other responses.. If the opposite were to happen i.e. Parent dies before the child process completes, then the child would become an  *orphan*  and would later be "adopted" by a special system process called **init**.